# Master Node becomes very slow

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Recently My ICp 2.1.0.1 environment (built on openStack VM) master node become very slow. Actually it is the Linux VM that very slow, not only for ICP product, even some general simple Linux command (ls, pwd, cd, etc.).

The thing here is, I didn't even use this environment, no workload, system completely idled.

I used top to monitor the CPU usage but didn't find long running processes taking long time.

How is that happen?

Note, this same issue occur at least twice. I just setup the env and leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

Although the root cause is not yet identified, but simply restart the cluster solved the issue:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/manage_cluster/restart_cluster.html

The restarting of docker takes several hours to finish. But finally it becomes fast.

I'm not sure if the same issue might happen again in the future. Monitoring..

Note that I didn't reboot the Linux VM as I found after rebooting Linux last time, some docker containers cannot startup successful, which lead me to check below part:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/troubleshoot/restart_master_console.html

Answer (score 0):

From ICP 2.1.0 release, there are some new features added, you need to ensure your VM hardware configuration matches the hardware requirements listed in below link, thanks.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html

Comment: Hi Sheng Feng, thanks. My OpenStack VM master node has 8CPU,16.0GMem,500GDisk, should be enough from requirement said.